# Better way to parse a config File in C++

Tags: c++, parsing

I am currently working on a parser project to get some file xml format 1 to another xml format.

I finished my project, and there is quiet a lot of parameters to know, most of them are paths to some files, lists of parameters, ...

I would like it to be easy to use so I create a settings.txt : it contains lines like

```
someparameter = defaultvalue
```

This file is easy to modify.I consider case where people want to parse files with same parameters, so my application is like :

```
Do you want to change parameters? (Y/N)
if(yes){
Do you want to change paramater 1? //If no value, [] stays
                   [pathbydefault]
}
...
else{ load from settings.txt}
```

To implement this, I use getline(), splitting on first '=' and put them in a std::map.
I think this is a bad choice, I searched and I found a lot of architecture for c++: list (really heavy for 10 parameters), table (not easy to read, the code is dark for other people).

What solution would you advise me to use?
Of course, i dont ask for implementation, just for some solution to consider.

Some info: I dont think if it matters a lot, but I work on Unix based system (Mac OS or Linux) so I cant use windows libraries. I saw a windows solution but I did not go further into this.

Comment: I use and recommend [SimpleIni](https://github.com/brofield/simpleini). Kind of ironic that an XML parser would not store its settings in an XML file. But I can't blame you, XML is far too unwieldy for this. The `[section] key = value` format is so much easier. Same as the Windows INI file format, but those APIs haven't been updated in this century, so you shouldn't be using them anyway, even on Windows.

Comment: Thank you, I felt like missing the better solution when i dont use Windows ini.
About settings format, I parse them with my own program but indeed, I could use c++

Comment: I have written classes to handle this in multiple languages over the years. you can make this code as complex or as simple as you desire to meet your needs. For example, do you allow comments and then you skip those. Can you have a comment at the end of the line? Do you trim the string to get rid of spaces? If yes, do you support an escape character to allow them embedded at the start or end? All that said, Using an existing library is a great idea if it matches your licensing requirements and, if you are not worried about it not existing in the future.

Comment: I have  a question about portability: if this code is to be used by other people on other plateforms, they will have to recompile my code. If I include those library, is nt it a bit dangerous (they may dont have the library) ?

Comment: If you use GTK. You can use the Glib KeyFile `save_to_file` and `load_from_file`. https://docs.gtk.org/glib/struct.KeyFile.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule of thumb with this stuff (IMHO) is to always use a good library to parse a standard data format, at least in any situation where your needs might continue to scale. For example, I tend to really be fond of JSON because it's a simple, easy to humanly read/write format, with quite a few good quality choices in C++.

This avoids having to deal with any bug prone parsing logic yourself. It also makes it very easy to e.g. write python scripts that generate or verify your configuration files (since python has very easy access to json as well, as about every language does).

In your code it may also be a good idea to cleanly separate the data format, and the collection into a map or whatever data structure you're using. That way, the portion of the code that will change if you decide to change which data format you use is contained.

Comment: I didn't thought to JSON, thank you very much! I am going to look further into this. The funny thing is I am going to use a very powerfull parser to use my personnal super weak parser ;)

Comment: @ThéophilePace if you feel like an answer is useful, feel free to upvote it ;-)

Comment: This is one of my first posts so I cant upvote before my reputation get higher...

Comment: @ThéophilePace Oh wow, I didn't know that you needed rep to upvote, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

One future consideration would be using XML transformation language to transition between an old XML file format and a new XML file format.  I'm not sure if you're already doing this or not, so if you are, please disregard.  If you're unfamiliar, the most common of these languages is XSLT (eXtensible Stylesheet Language Transformations).

Rather than having the end-user enter a myriad of options/paths/values to an INI-styled configuration file, the end-user would ideally only supply XML (which can easily be edited by hand) / XSLT template files to the XSLT processor.  You could update your C++ application to focus less on obtaining every input from the end-user and more on creating/choosing the right XML/XSLT template files.

As you mention working on Unix-based systems, you might want to consider this processor: http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/

Comment: I dont know about XSLT, I am going to consider that. My problem was that my XML file are very, very huge (Millions of lines) and I am not sure I will be able to get them in RAM in the future so I try not to load them entirely.

About the miriad of parameters, people can modify settings.txt  and say no to 'change default parameters'.

Thank you for Xalan, it looks like I should have been using it since the beginning...

Comment: Understood and thanks for the feedback.  Once nice thing about transitioning from INI-style settings to XML settings is that, with properly written XSLT, you can basically do away with the middle-man C++ app and let the XSLT code do all the work for you.  Good luck!